# Unity5 render at half resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to get Unity to render at (for instance) half resolution to get better performance. I first created a script that added a new camera with a plane in front of it, then made the original main-camera render to a texture, and then I showed that texture on the plane. This works.

However, I then found out about the method [Graphics.SetRenderTarget(...)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.SetRenderTarget.html). It sounded very promising. But it doesn't seem to do what I expected it to.

So I tried the following:

```
RenderTexture texture = new RenderTexture(Screen.width / 2, Screen.width / 2, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
Graphics.SetRenderTarget(texture);
```

But this doesn't seem to change anything. I was hoping this would make Unity render at half resolution. (I tried this in a 'Start' method, as well as in 'Update'.)

Don't I understand the functionality of this method. Am I using it wrong? Or is there something I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity provides a Method called [Screen.SetResolution](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html).
But be aware that you shouldn't change the resolution often. Let the user decide which resolution is the best for him. SetResolution need a short refresh so the user notice if you change the resolution while playing.

Using the RenderTexture to control it at runtime sounds very hacky and I'm not sure if you get a noticable performance boost. Maybe the "double" camera cause lags and other problems as well.